# How to use OpenIddict AuthServer and Web API in same project

Tags: asp.net-web-api, .net-6.0, openiddict

I've built an OpenIddict OAuth server using [the marvelous guide by Robin van der Knaap](https://dev.to/robinvanderknaap/setting-up-an-authorization-server-with-openiddict-part-i-introduction-4jid) although I've actually implemented it using Identity instead of cookies.

I'm also trying to run a Web API from the same project because the end customer only wants a single system to call.

At the moment I'm doing all my endpoint testing in postman.

This user info endpoint in the AuthorisationController works fine:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("~/connect/userinfo")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Userinfo()
{
    var claimsPrincipal = (await HttpContext.AuthenticateAsync(OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)).Principal;

    return Ok(new
    {
        Name = claimsPrincipal.GetClaim(OpenIddictConstants.Claims.Subject),
        Occupation = "Developer",
        Age = 43
    });
}
```

But when I try to call this custom Web API controller endpoint (https://<domain.com>/api/Test/):

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class TestController : ControllerBase
{
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        return Ok("hello");
    }
}
```

I just get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: An identity cannot be extracted from
> this request. This generally indicates that the OpenIddict server
> stack was asked to validate a token for an endpoint it doesn't manage.
> To validate tokens received by custom API endpoints, the OpenIddict
> validation handler (e.g
> OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme or
> OpenIddictValidationOwinDefaults.AuthenticationType) must be used
> instead.    at
> OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerHandlers.ValidateAuthenticationDemand.HandleAsync(ProcessAuthenticationContext
> context)    at
> OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher.DispatchAsync[TContext](TContext
> context)    at
> OpenIddict.Server.OpenIddictServerDispatcher.DispatchAsync[TContext](TContext
> context)    at
> OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore.OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreHandler.HandleAuthenticateAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationHandler`1.AuthenticateAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationService.AuthenticateAsync(HttpContext
> context, String scheme)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.Policy.PolicyEvaluator.AuthenticateAsync(AuthorizationPolicy
> policy, HttpContext context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext
> context)

My Program.cs looks like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using OAuthServer;
using OAuthServer.Data;
using OpenIddict.Server.AspNetCore;
using OpenIddict.Validation.AspNetCore;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
{
    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString);

    // Register the entity sets needed by OpenIddict.
    options.UseOpenIddict();
});

builder.Services.AddOpenIddict()
        // Register the OpenIddict core components.
        .AddCore(options =>
        {
            // Configure OpenIddict to use the EF Core stores/models.
            options.UseEntityFrameworkCore()
                .UseDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>();
        })

        // Register the OpenIddict server components.
        .AddServer(options =>
        {
            options
                .AllowClientCredentialsFlow()
                .AllowAuthorizationCodeFlow().RequireProofKeyForCodeExchange()
                .AllowRefreshTokenFlow();

            options
                .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                .SetAuthorizationEndpointUris("/connect/authorize")
                .SetTokenEndpointUris("/connect/token")
                .SetUserinfoEndpointUris("/connect/userinfo");

            // Encryption and signing of tokens TODO: Replace with x.509 cert
            options
                .AddEncryptionCertificate(CertificateHelper.LoadCertificateFromKeyVault(builder.Configuration["KeyVault:Name"], builder.Configuration["OAuth:EncryptionCertName"]))
                .AddSigningCertificate(CertificateHelper.LoadCertificateFromKeyVault(builder.Configuration["KeyVault:Name"], builder.Configuration["OAuth:EncryptionCertName"]))
                /*.AddEphemeralEncryptionKey()
                .AddEphemeralSigningKey()*/
                .DisableAccessTokenEncryption();

            // Register scopes (permissions)
            options.RegisterScopes("api");

            // Register the ASP.NET Core host and configure the ASP.NET Core-specific options.
            options
                .UseAspNetCore()
                .EnableTokenEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableAuthorizationEndpointPassthrough()
                .EnableUserinfoEndpointPassthrough();
        })
        .AddValidation();

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options => options.DefaultScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);

builder.Services.AddHostedService<TestData>();

builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddControllers();




var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
}
else
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();


app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

How can I make `[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]` work on custom API endpoints?

### UPDATE

I have a feeling the Web API bit is a red-herring and the issue is something more fundamental. I tried to add an MVC action in the same AuthorisationController:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
[HttpGet("~/connect/hello")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Hello()
{
    return Ok("hi");
}
```

But that gives the same error.

I think I should probably just be using [Authorize] without specifying the scheme (which is what I was originally trying to do) but that always gives unauthorised.....

I suspect this article has something in it I need, but it's for an old version of OpenIddict (I'm using 3.1.1) and I can't figure out the current behaviour.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out I was just using the wrong scheme on the authorize attribute. I needed to change:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictServerAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

to:

```
[Authorize(AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)]
```

And if you want to avoid adding the scheme in the attribute then you need to add this to your service configuration:

```
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = OpenIddictValidationAspNetCoreDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
});
```

NOTE: This seems to conflict with the information on
[The OpenIddict ASP.NET Core server cannot be used as the default scheme handler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59790883/the-openiddict-asp-net-core-server-cannot-be-used-as-the-default-scheme-handler) but it's what worked for me.

Although this won't play nice with Identity sign-in (unless I fiddle with the sign-in call) so I left it out.

Comment: What if you don't want it to be the default?  I can't find anything on this anywhere.  I have an existing application with Cookie Authentication but I want to allow open id tokens as well.